# Java Dependency issue, not working for hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Hello I am trying to follow this tutorial ::http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm

my code in caseyou want to have a dig is here:
https://github.com/ArthurGibbs/Centaurus-

Im using restx framework.

I am trying to use hibernate to access a local database. however when i try compile my code i get a dependency error:

```
src/main/java/centaurus/service/UserDao.java:7: error: package org.hibernate does not exist
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
```

but i have included it in my pom so i dont understand why I am getting the error.

this is my class where there error points to
    package centaurus.service;

```
import centaurus.entity.GameUser;

import restx.factory.Component;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

@Component
public class UserDao {
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().
                    configure().
                    //addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                    addAnnotatedClass(GameUser.class).
                    buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        UserDao ME = new UserDao();
    }

    /* Method to CREATE an employee in the database */
    public Integer addEmployee(String email){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer employeeID = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            GameUser employee = new GameUser();
            employee.setEmail(email);
            employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void saveId() {
        addEmployee("bob");
    }
}
```

new to hibernate, and not very experienced with maven. please help or let me know how to help you help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your full pom file and not only excerpts ...But i assume you have it put into `<pluginManagement>...</pluginManagemnt>`?

Comment: Try an `mvn clean` first and see if that helps.  Otherwise, run a `mvn dependency:tree` and see if Maven forgot a dependency somewhere, which it sometimes does.

Comment: Heya, I regularly use clean before i retry after a failed build, mvn dependency:tree did not seem to make a difference,  thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I am using restx, it does not read the pom, it reads the md.restx.json file where i was missing the dependencies dependancies